# Time complexity of dependent nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I was trying to find the time complexity of this nested loop

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    n--;
    x++;
  }
}
```

If there wasn't a `n--` it would be `n*n` , O(n<sup>2</sup>) right?

But what if `n` reduces every time second loop runs?

What's the time complexity and big O of this nested loop?

If I consider n = 5, x equals 4, the second loop runs 4 time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time complexity of the code is O(n). `n` is reduced by half for every iteration of the outer loop.

So we have `n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + ... + n/2^k = O(n)`

where `k` is the number of iterations of the outer loop (basically `i`).

Note that the time complexity is independent of x.

> If there wasn't a `n--` it would be `n*n` , O(n<sup>2</sup>) right?

Yes

Comment: What's the value of k?

Comment: @KellyBundy `k` is the number of iterations of the outer loop.

Comment: @danh Note that both `j` and `n` are moving towards each other, so by the time the loop condition `j <= n` is broken, they will have met in the middle.

Comment: But what is it? (Looking for an expression involving n)

Comment: @KellyBundy Good question. Not sure, I wasn't able to find an expression involving n even after  plotting.

Comment: Yes, I'm also having difficulty with it, as the outer loop is also affected by the decreasing n. I think log2(n) is a rough upper limit, but it's less because i surpasses n before log2(n) iterations.

Comment: Btw I also don't understand the `+k` and don't see how you divide/round. For example for n=5, the inner loop iterates for j=1,2,3, so `5/2` = 3.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah, I mistakenly thought that `n` was being incremented by 1 by the outer loop. Let me fix that.

Comment: Ok, and now if you're rounding the division results, rounding up for .5, then the iteration number terms seem to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it's O(n): You only enter the inner loop body if `j <= n`, and since `j` is positive, `n` must also be positive. But you decrease `n` every time, which you can only do O(n) times (where n is the starting value) and still have `n` positive.